# How to get value from ng-model in directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have code:

```
<input check-value-type-array type-value="node.type_value" type-element="node.type" ng-value="item" class="form-control">
```

And directive:

```
.directive('checkValueTypeArray', function() {
         return {

             restrict: 'A',
             require: 'ngModel',
             scope: {
                 typeElement: '=',
                 typeValue: '=',
                 ngModel: '='
             },

             link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {


                 ngModel.$validators.required = function(v) {}

             }
```

How to get ng-model inside directive and do validation:

```
ngModel.$validators.required = function (v) {
}
```

Comment: `scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Minor alteration, you're looking for ngModel.$modelValue:

```
ngModel.$validators.required = (value) => {
  // the value of the model will be ngModel.$modelValue
}
```

Comment: Inside input it shows ` ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched`;

Comment: Log out what ngModel looks like, and 'value' inside that $validators method. See what they look like.